# Grails GORM JOIN in query

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have an entity that is join entity between `Notification` and `User`:

```
class NotificationRecipient implements Serializable {
    Notification notification

    User recipientUser

    static mapping = {
        table 'notification_recipient'
        version false

        notification cascade: 'all'
        recipientUser cascade: 'all'
        id generator: 'assigned', composite: ['notification', 'recipientUser']
    }
}
```

I want to create query that receive all notifications assigned to the specified user, but I want `notification` field to be populated to avoid N+1 selects while iterate over result (1 query for retreive list and one select per each notification field access with default lazy loading) as mentioned http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#criteria in *Querying with Eager Fetching* section.

I don't want to change `mapping` and set `notification` to `lazy: false`, but specify it in query (http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#fetchingDSL).

My query is (as docs says):

```
def resut = NotificationRecipient.createCriteria().list(options?.params ?: [:]) {
    eq("recipientUser.id", userId)
    join 'notification'
}
```

but still N+1 queries are generated.

I have also tried with setting Fetch mode:

```
NotificationRecipient.createCriteria().list(options?.params ?: [:]) {
    eq("recipientUser.id", userId)
    fetchMode "notification", FetchMode.JOIN
}
```

without success.

Can you explain me this behaviour of Grails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunalelly it is a Hibernate or Grails bug:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9285

The solution is remove compound primary key `id generator: 'assigned', composite: ['notification', 'recipientUser']` .

For compoun primary key joins doesn't work. Also order by is not working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

```
NotificationRecipient.findAllByRecepientUser(user, [fetch:[notification:'eager']])
```

A similar request works great (without the N+1) on my system.

I would also check if there are lazy fetched parameters on Notification (the Notification is loaded eagerly, but some properties in notifications are not simple types but Domain objects that need to be lazy loaded).